# How to log http request & response with header & body inside @AroundInvoke

Tags: java, quarkus

I need to be able to log http request & response with header & body.

Currently I have an Interceptor and a `@AroundInvoke` advise which logs the body.
But is it possible to also get hold of the http headers? In some way?

I have included some code snippets below
The project is using Resteasy, ie. having quarkus-rest-client dependency in pom

```
//@LoggedClient not included in example
@Priority(0) 
@Interceptor
public class LoggingInterceptor {
    
    @AroundInvoke
    Object logInvocation(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception { 

        logRequest(ctx);
        try {
            Object response = ctx.proceed();
            logResponse(response);
            return response;
        } catch (WebApplicationException e) { 
            logError(e);
            return e;
        } 
    }
    private void logError(WebApplicationException e) {/* impl */}
    private void logResponse(Object response) {/* impl */}
    private void logRequest(InvocationContext ctx) {/* impl which logs httpheader & body(class,method & request) */}
}

@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/offer")
//@LoggedClient not included in example
public class MyResource {

    @Inject
    @RestClient
    MyClient client;
    
    @POST
    @Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response create(MyRequest req) {             
        MyResponse response = client.create(req);
        return Response.ok().entity(response).build();
    }   
}

@Path("/somepath")
@RegisterRestClient
public interface MyClient {
    
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/create")
    MyResponse create(MyRequest req);
}
```

Comment: We would need more details about what you're using: resteasy, reactive routes?

Comment: Can you add a snippet of code of your `Interceptor` for instance to better understand the context ?